# Using seek() in Python

Tags: python

I am working on reading specific holter data (.ecg files) and copying specific data, as specified by the user, into a new file. Basically, I only want to read the data into memory that is necessary. Is there a way to use .seek() to only read in data bytes from (start, end)?

```
start = args.packet_start
end = args.packet_end

try:

    print("Beginning copying of holter data...")

    # Output the specific holter data
    output_file = open("copied_holter.ecg", 'w')

    # Read part of holter file into memory
    holter = open(args.filename, 'rb')
    data = holter.seek()

# Parse through holter data and copy to file
    for index in range(start, end+1):
    data_list = data[index]
    output_file.write(data_list)

    # Close the file streams
    holter.close()
    output_file.close()  

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Exiting program, due to exception.")
    exit(1)

print "Finished data copying operations!"
```

Comment: You should `seek(start)` and then `read(end-start)` (this reads a bounded length of data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`seek` will move the pointer to specified location, not return data. `read` willy return number of bytes specified. Also you should use `with` statement when working with files or file like objects.

```
with open(args.filename, 'rb') as holter, open("copied_holter.ecg", 'w') as output_file:
    holter.seek(start)
    data = holter.read(end-start)
    output_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I did that and got an error that said "string index out of range"

Comment: You are probably still using you loop. You don't need to use that as `holter.read(end-start)` will return all the content you need to write to output_file.